# Does whats app save your contacts profile pix on your device

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am currently working on a chat app like WhatsApp , where my users has to be able to view their contacts profile pix offline. I would like to know what approach WhatsApp uses to make profile pix available offline, and what format are the pictures been saved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for Whatsapp support, not a question about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where my users has to be able to view their contacts profile pix offline.

if you want to cache images to a device you can use a plugin like   [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

> A flutter library to show images from the internet and keep them in the cache directory.

example

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
 ),
```

The cached network images stores and retrieves files using the [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_cache_manager).

Comment: How long can this images be persisted on the cache memory?

Comment: By default the cached files are stored in the temporary directory of the app. This means the OS can delete the files any time.

Information about the files is stored in a database using sqflite. The file name of the database is the key of the cacheManager, that's why that has to be unique.

This cache information contains the end date till when the file is valid and the eTag to use with the http cache-control.  read more from  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager